# Linear transformation and its kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I'm working on a linear algebra set of exercises and I'm a bit perplexed by one. Basically, the task is really quite simple it looks like, but I'm extremely uncertain about my solutions:
**1. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be linear transformation $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto(x+y,2y-z,2x-w)$. Find the $f$ matrix from standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ to standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$.**

Here I just went with:
$$f(e_1) = f(1,0,0,0) = (1,0,2) = (1,0,0) + 2(0,0,1) = e_1 + 2e_3$$
$$f(e_2) = f(0,1,0,0) = (1,2,0) = (1,0,0) + 2(0,1,0) = e_1 + 2e_2$$
$$f(e_3) = f(0,0,1,0) = (0,-1,0) = -1(0,1,0) = -e_2$$
$$f(e_4) = f(0,0,0,1) = (0,0,-1) = -1(0,0,1) = -e_3$$

For:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
    0&2&-1&0\\
    2&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I believe this part is correct. Now the issues come as follows:

**2. What is the image of the vector $(1,1,2,-1)$ in this transformation?**

I solved this as follows:
$$A \cdot v = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
    0&2&-1&0\\
    2&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

However, I'm not certain I'm actually calculating the right thing here. What does the "image of a vector" mean; is it just a multiplication, or? I can't find anything in the materials and awfully little online probably because it's such a basic thing.

**3. Kernel for the transformation and its dimension**
So this would be:
$$Ax = 0$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
    0&2&-1&0\\
    2&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=0$$

So basically just solving the matrix.

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\
    0&2&-1&0&0\\
    2&0&0&-1&0\\\end{bmatrix}

Switch rows 2 & 3.
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\
    2&0&0&-1&0\\
    0&2&-1&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}

$R_2 - 2R_1$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\
    0&-2&0&-1&0\\
    0&2&-1&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}

$R_3 + R_2$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\
    0&-2&0&-1&0\\
    0&0&-1&-1&0\\\end{bmatrix}

$R_2 \cdot (-\frac{1}{2})$
$R_3 \cdot (-1)$

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
    0&0&1&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}

$R_1 - R_2$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\
    0&1&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
    0&0&1&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}

So basically:
\begin{bmatrix}&x_1 & & & & &- &x_4 &= &0\\
& & x_2& & & &+ &x_4 &= &0\\
& & & & x_3& &+ &x_4 &= &0\\
\end{bmatrix}

or...
\begin{bmatrix}&x_1 & = &\frac{1}{2}x_4\\
&x_2 &= &-\frac{1}{2}x_4\\
&x_3 &= &-x_4\\
&x_4 &= &x_4\\
\end{bmatrix}

For:
$$ker A = s\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\\
-1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}, s\in\mathbb{R}$$

So this is a 1-dimensional basis, because there's only one vector, right?

**4. Image for the transformation and its dimensions.**
$im(f) = \{f(v) \in (x+y,2y-z,2x-w): v \in (x,y,z,w)\}$ is basically $Col A$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\
    1&2&0\\
    0&-1&0\\
    0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Reduced echelon form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Image being:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + u\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, s,t,u\in\mathbb{R}$$

And this is three-dimensional, right? Does the fact that the matrix is basically a unit matrix matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That is correct.
2. That is correct too, but why not just $F(1,1,2,-1)=(2,0,3)$?
3. The computation and the conclusion are correct, but the notation for the kernel is awkward. It should be$$\ker F=\left\{s\begin{bmatrix}\frac12\\-\frac12\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,s\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$Note that it's the kernel of $F$, not of $A$.
4. That's a complicated way of saying that the image is $\Bbb R^3$. Anyway, it follows from that rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\operatorname{Im}(F)=3$. So, since $\operatorname{Im}(F)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, it must *be* $\Bbb R^3$.